# DNN - Adding a secure folder

Tags: module, dotnetnuke

I'm currently coding a module where users can add secure folders.

But the instance method requires a parameter of an instance name, i've no idea what they mean. Could someone explain it to me?

```
  DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.SecureFolderProvider.Instance("Test2").AddFolder(txtFolderName.Text, new FolderMappingInfo
            {
                PortalID = base.PortalId,
                MappingName = txtFolderName.Text
            });
```

Any suggestions what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help of garethbh, i came up with this:

```
                  // Get folder mapping
                     var folderMapping = FolderMappingController.Instance.GetFolderMapping(PortalId, "Secure");

                  // Add folder and get the result back of the folder information
                    var folder = FolderManager.Instance.AddFolder(new FolderMappingInfo
                    {
                        FolderProviderType = folderMapping.FolderProviderType,
                        FolderMappingID = 9,
                        Priority = 2,
                        PortalID = PortalId,
                    }, portalFilePath);
```

This works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the name of your folder mapping provider type. If you search for usages of SecureFolderProvider's base class (FolderProvider), you'll see what you need.

Eg:

```
 var folderMapping = FolderMappingController.Instance.GetFolderMapping(PortalId, "Secure");

 if (folderMapping != null)
 {
     SecureFolderProvider.Instance(folderMapping.FolderProviderType).AddFolder(folderPath, folderMapping);
 }
```

I've never actually used the secure folder provider before so I'm just guessing you need the one with the 'Secure' mapping name (but you may want to use 'Database' depending on your needs or create your own folder provider). See the FolderMappings table in the database for available types.

From the DNN wiki http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/Page/Folder-Types and http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/Page/Folder-providers